# If the address of a function can not be resolved during deduction, is it SFINAE or a compiler error?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, overload-resolution

In C++0x SFINAE rules have been simplified such that any invalid expression or type that occurs in the "immediate context" of deduction does not result in a compiler error but rather in deduction failure (SFINAE).

My question is this:
If I take the address of an overloaded function and it can not be resolved, is that failure in the immediate-context of deduction?
(i.e is it a hard error or SFINAE if it can not be resolved)?

Here is some sample code:

```
struct X
{
  // template<class T> T* foo(T,T); // lets not over-complicate things for now
  void foo(char);
  void foo(int);
};


template<class U> struct S
{
  template<int> struct size_map 
  { typedef int type; };


// here is where we take the address of a possibly overloaded function
  template<class T> void f(T, 
      typename size_map<sizeof(&U::foo)>::type* = 0); 


  void f(...);
};

int main()
{
  S<X> s;

// should this cause a compiler error because 'auto T = &X::foo' is invalid?
  s.f(3);  

}
```

Gcc 4.5 states that this is a compiler error, and clang spits out an assertion violation.

Here are some more related questions of interest:

Does the FCD-C++0x clearly specify what should happen here?
Are the compilers wrong in rejecting this code?
Does the "immediate-context" of deduction need to be defined a little better?

Thanks!

Comment: In the next time, please press the 1/0 button instead of using `<pre>` to format your code :) It got all messed up. I think it's a good question though, i've wondered multiple times about this term "immediate context" :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
template<class T> void f(T, 
    typename size_map<sizeof(&U::foo)>::type* = 0);
```

This doesn't work, because `U` does not participate in deduction. While `U` is a dependent type, during deduction for `f` it's treated like a fixed type spelled with a nondependent name. You need to add it to the parameter list of `f`

```
/* fortunately, default arguments are allowed for 
 * function templates by C++0x */
template<class T, class U1 = U> void f(T, 
    typename size_map<sizeof(&U1::foo)>::type* = 0);
```

So in your case because `U::foo` does not depend on parameters of `f` itself, you receive an error while implicitly instantiating `S<X>` (try to comment out the call, and it should still fail). The FCD says at `14.7.1/1`

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the deﬁnitions or default arguments, of the class member functions, member classes, static data members and member templates;

That is, if you implicitly instantiate `S<X>` the following function template declaration will be instantiated

```
template<class T> void S<X>::f(T, 
  typename size_map<sizeof(&X::foo)>::type* = 0);
```

Analysis on that template declaration will then find that it can't resolve the reference to `X::foo` and error out. If you add `U1`, the template declaration will not yet try to resolve the reference to `U1::foo` (since `U1` is a parameter of `f`), and will thus remain valid and SFINAE when `f` is tried to be called.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification here :)  So this is a bug in gcc 4.5 since this errors out:
`template<class T, class U1=U> void f(T, typename size_map<sizeof(decltype(&U1::foo))>::type* = 0)`
I think the problem is their decltype implementation.

Comment: @Faisal, yep i think this is a bug in GCC. clang takes it with the decltype too (and they also fixed your crash once i told dgregor about it xD).

Comment: Note, in case it helps: Without the `U1` template parameter to the member function `f`, as noted in the answer, the declaration of `f` will be created by the compiler when class `S<X>` is instantiated, but the function `f` itself will **NOT** be instantiated until the time it is actually called somewhere.  Because the creation of the DECLARATION is **not** OVERLOAD RESOLUTION, SFINAE does *not* apply, but the compiler still looks at the declaration it has created to try to resolve `X::foo` (and hence fails because SFINAE does not apply).

Comment: ... Only when SFINAE applies (by postponing creation and EVALUATION of the declaration until the time of overload resolution) does the non-existence of `U1::foo` (defaulting to `X::foo`) simply result in SFINAE.  (Or so I think.)