# Can I use boost::enable_if on a member function?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, enable-if

I'm writing a template class, and I want to allow an additional method to exist only for a certain template type.  Currently the method exists for all template types, but causes a compilation error for all other types.

Complicating this is that it's an overloaded operator().  Not sure if what I want to do is actually possible here.

Here's what I have now:

```
template<typename T, typename BASE>
class MyClass  : public BASE
{
public:

    typename T& operator() (const Utility1<BASE>& foo);
    typename T const& operator() (const Utility2<BASE>& foo) const;
};
```

I want the `T&` version always available, but the `T const&` version only available if `Utility2<BASE>` is valid.  Right now, both methods exist, but attempting to use the const version gives a weird compilation error if `Utility2<BASE>` is invalid.  I'd rather have a sensible error, or even a "no such member function" error.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**:  After reading through the boost docs, here's what I've come up with, and it seems to work:

```
template<typename T, typename BASE>
class MyClass  : public BASE
{
public:

    typename T& operator() (const Utility1<BASE>& foo);

    template<typename U>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<Utility2<BASE>, U>, T>::type const &
    operator() (const U& foo) const;
};
```

So that method doesn't exist unless someone tries to use it with Utility2, and they can only create a Utility2 if it's valid for that BASE type.  But when it's not valid for that BASE type, MyClass will not waste time creating the accessor method.

Comment: what do you mean by `Utility2<BASE>` is "valid"?

Comment: Utility2 tries to call a method on BASE.  Only one type of BASE actually has that method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937425/boostenable-if-class-template-method

Comment: If you want a compiler error anyway, static assertion might be a better idea.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer a compile error.  Basically, no one should attempt to use `Utility2` except in a very specific case.  Catching that kind of mistake at compile time is preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but not with the class template parameter directly.  `boost::enable_if` can only be used with a template parameter on the method itself.  So, with a little typedef usage:

```
template<typename T, typename BASE>
class MyClass  : public BASE
{
public:
  typedef Utility2<BASE> util;

  typename T& operator() (const Utility1<BASE>& foo);

  template<typename U>
  typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<util, U>, T>::type const &
  operator() (const U& foo) const;
};
```

This works, because Utility2 can only be created from a certain BASE type.  So if the BASE type is something else, the const version of operator() won't exist.

So, it's a very minor thing.  It doesn't gain me much.  But it was neat to do.